# Is it possible to update R in the terminal?

Tags: r, macos, version, updates, osx-mavericks

I was wondering if the is an R command, that allows to update the version of R. So far I only found the command that allows to update installed packages. (By the way: **is there a command that checks for all available updates, and starts the Installation**)

Or do I have to download and install the package, each time there is a new R version available? (in my case from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)

Comment: See the installr package.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I believe "installr" is currently Windows only.

Comment: For everything, except Linux (with their package management) the only way is just check the CRAN for update.

Answer (score 3):

```
install.packages('devtools') #assuming it is not already installed

library(devtools)

install_github('andreacirilloac/updateR')

library(updateR)

updateR(admin_password = 'Admin user password')
```

You can find in-depth tutorial on how to use updateR package on this [blog](https://andreacirilloblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/updater-package-update-r-version-with-a-function-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: This did not work for me on Monterey (12.6). It might be https://github.com/AndreaCirilloAC/updateR/issues/37.